# How can I substitute a name of a variable into a file name within a command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to make a script that runs through all the machines available and saves some data into my home folder.

```
machines=`cat $OAR_FILE_NODES | uniq`
for machine in ${machines}
do
    echo "connecting to:" ${machine}
    oarsh ${machine} 'tar -zcvf data_${machine}.tar.gz /tmp/data'
done
```

The problem is that all data gets saved to `data_.tar.gz` archive, overwriting it several times.

How can I make the shell substitute the variable **machine** into the command passed to oarsh?

Comment: What if you use double quotes in the `oarsh` line? This way, `$machine` will get expanded.

Comment: Like this `oarsh ${machine} tar -zcvf "data_${machine}.tar.gz" /tmp/data` ?

Comment: Like `oarsh ${machine} "tar -zcvf data_${machine}.tar.gz /tmp/data"`.

Comment: @fedorqui Thank you! I tested it and it works!

Comment: Nice to read that! I posted as an answer to make it clear for future people entering in your question. Mark as accepted if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen on the comments, it was about the variable not expanding because of the single quote `'`. By changing to double quotes `"` the variable is expanded properly:

```
oarsh ${machine} "tar -zcvf data_${machine}.tar.gz /tmp/data"
                 ^                                          ^
```

Note that when using a single quote, what `oarsh` would receive is the literal:

```
tar -zcvf data_${machine}.tar.gz /tmp/data
```

while using double quotes would provide the `$machine` value replaced:

```
tar -zcvf data_THE_MACHINE.tar.gz /tmp/data
```